# sql query to add days to specific column date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql database with `expiry_date` column.

I want to **add 7 days** to **all member's expiry date** which are **greater than today**. (say 1 April 2016)

I want to run **sql query** in **phpmyadmin**
Help appreciated.

Comment: Hint:  `update`, `date_add()` and `where`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
UPDATE <table> 
SET expiry_date = DATE_ADD(expiry_date , INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
WHERE DATE(expiry_date) >= DATE(NOW());
```

Comment: Than you for very very quick help